# Couldn't connect to mongoDB database error. queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0-69fzw.mongodb.net

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Node.js with [**MongoDB**](https://charts.mongodb.com/) as database and using Mongoose. I have started working on in after a few days break. Now whenever I try to run my Server.js (server file), it gives me an error:

> Couldn't Connect Database Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0-69fzw.mongodb.net

I am not facing any internet connection issues, but I am not being able to connect with my database.

Here is my Keys.js code in which connection string is provided

```
module.exports = {
mongoURI:
"mongodb+srv://yasir:<password>@cluster0-fxwlb.mongodb.net/test? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority"
//copied connection string,
};

While my Server.js file is  

const database = require("./keys/keys").mongoURI;
const port = process.env.port || 3000;

mongoose
.connect(database, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then((data) => {
console.log("Database Connected ");
})
.catch((err) => {
console.log("Couldn't Connect Database " + err);
});
```

Comment: Can you post your code? and how is your connection being instantiated in your code?

Comment: You can edit the question to include the information needed.

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow so i am learning about all that stuff.But i think now i have provided all the required information above now

Comment: Can you check if it helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334603/cant-connect-to-mongodb-atlas. As you do not provided the connection string, i can only guess based in connection error. According to this link, you must change the url connection string

Comment: Sir my connection String is given below                                                                                          mongodb+srv://yasir:<password>@cluster0-fxwlb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: That is it man, in the stackoverflow link above, they say to change the connection string from `mongodb+srv://` to `mongodb://`

Comment: Now my connection string is                                    
"mongodb://malik:<password>@cluster0-fxwlb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"                                                                                        but now i'm getting another error and that is.                                                           Couldn't Connect Database MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0-fxwlb.mongodb.net

Comment: I posted answer, can you check if it helps? If you have any problem, you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you changed your connection string to `mongodb://` revert it back to `mongodb+srv://`

I successfully were able to connect to a mongodb instance, using the following:

1. Configured a account
2. Got the connection string from database as service platform as follow:

> mongodb+srv://[user]:[password]@cluster0-xxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority

3. Notice that inside square brackets its the **user** and **password** credentials from my account and that they are split by a colon.
4. Inside the brackets I should put current user and password credentials to it become a valid connection string.
5. The final string will look something like:

   ```
   mongodb+srv://myuser:abc123@cluster0-xxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
   ```

You should replace possible meta characters that comes in your connection string. The meta characters are in format

My final connection string in nodejs code:

```
const url = 'mongodb+srv://myuser:abc123@cluster0-xxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

If this does not help, i suggest you to access the [Troubleshoot Connection Issues](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/) from your database provider.