# how to connect my node project to MongoDb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i try to connect my node project to mongoDb using
this url.
"mongodb+srv::@cluster0.herrxnf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

of course, i provided user and password.
but it shows an error
`{ errno: undefined, code: 'ETIMEOUT', syscall: 'queryTxt', hostname: 'cluster0.herrxnf.mongodb.net' }`

Comment: Can you change your wifi or use the mobile hotspot and also whitelist the current connected IP on MongoDB and see if that works ? This question might help resolve your issue. @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334603/cant-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-querytxt-etimeout